# Add the SSH2 extension to MAMP PRO

Tags: php, macos, mamp-pro, libssh2, ssh2-sftp

I am trying to add the ssh2 extension to MAMP PRO without success.  Any help would be appreciated!

I've gone through [these](https://www.dionysopoulos.me/249-add-the-ssh2-extension-to-mamp.html) two [tutorials](https://www.allsupported.com/install-ssh2-on-osx-mamp-pro/), but neither successfully added ssh2.

After completing the tutorials I checked my PHP info page, but found no information about SSH2.

I'm working on OS X Yosemite version 10.10.5, MAMP PRO version 3.5 and 
PHP version 5.6.10

Comment: Just received this email from MAMP Support:

"At this time you cannot add a php module.

Adding a php module is not possible in MAMP PRO 3. When the main PHP source is compiled, it creates header files, which are needed, for compiling additional modules. MAMP PRO 3 does not include these files."